# $watch fires in promise "then" for array but not value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reasonably new to angular and I am seeing the following strange issue occur and I'm not sure why.  I have a simple controller that has 2 properties on the scope - "sentences" and "countVal" which I display at the top of my html page.

I have a factory "ModelState" that holds my data that my service "UpdatingService" populates.

The strange issue I am seeing is that ModelState.values.push(data); causes the array length value to go to one, but the count value does not increase.  The $watch in TestCtrl also does not log to the console.  I'm sure there is something wrong I'm doing but I can't figure out what.  Here is my html (with the script inlined).  Many thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TestCtrl">

<p>Array length : {{ sentences.length }}</p>
<p>Count value  : {{ countVal }}</p>
<br>

</body>

<script>
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, ModelState, UpdatingService) {

  $scope.sentences = ModelState.values;
  $scope.countVal  = ModelState.countVal;

  $scope.$watch("countVal", function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(newValue,"  ",oldValue);
  }, true);
});

testApp.factory('ModelState', function(){
  return {
    values : [],
    countVal : 0
  };
});

testApp.service("UpdatingService", function($http, $timeout, ModelState, $q){
   var service = {

    getData:function(){
      var promise = $http.get("http://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler");

      promise.success(function(data){
        ModelState.values.push(data);
        ModelState.countVal++;
      });

      return promise;
    }
  };

  service.getData();

  return service;
});

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write inside your controller:

```
$scope.sentences = ModelState.values;
$scope.countVal  = ModelState.countVal;
```

you assigning a **reference** to `sentences` array - from now on `ModelState` and `$scope` have a reference to the same instance of `Array`

and you are assigning **value** to `countVal` property - from now on `ModelState` and `$scope` point to  **2 different** instances of `Number`

Then when you `push` new item to `sentences` its `length` change is reflected in view however the `$scope.countVal` didn't change since you only changed the property of `ModelState.countVal`.

One way to solve this is to simply assign `$scope.ModelState = ModelState` and use its properties directly in view:

```
<p>Array length : {{ ModelState.sentences.length }}</p>
<p>Count value  : {{ ModelState.countVal }}</p>
```

Another way would be to use methods of scope to access `ModelState` values like so:

```
$scope.sentenecesLength = function(){
  return ModelState.sentences.length;
};
$scope.countVal = function(){
  return ModelState.countVal;
};

<p>Array length : {{ sentenecesLength() }}</p>
<p>Count value  : {{ countVal() }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Does this mean that I can't use a Factory for ModelState? If I used a service instead would this work?  Basically I am trying to  be able to inject into controllers some concept of shared state between them.

Comment: `service` and `factory` only differ in a way they create shared, single instance object - so both of them are perfectly valid way of keeping state/data/behaviour that is shared between controllers.

Comment: Perfect answer. Your code example really helps. Thanks again.